# Bash convert a number of epoch values to datetime

Tags: bash, unix-timestamp

I have a number of files in the form `foo_[SECONDS.MILLISECONDS]_bar.tar.gz` and for each file I would like to be to get a datetime value (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS) for each file.

So far I have

```
ls -1 /filestore/*.tar.gz | cut -d _ -f 2  | date -f -
```

But this errors along the lines of

> date: invalid date '1467535262.712041352'

**How should a bash pipeline of epoch values be converted into a datetime string?**

### MWE

```
mkdir tmpBLAH
touch tmpBLAH/foo_1467483118.640314986_bar.tar.gz
touch tmpBLAH/foo_1467535262.712041352_bar.tar.gz
ls -1 tmpBLAH/*.tar.gz | cut -d _ -f 2 | date -f -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for f in /filestore/*.tar.gz; do
    epoch=${f#*_}
    date -d @${epoch%%.*} +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
done
```

The syntax of the `date` command differs between platforms; I have assumed GNU `date`, as commonly found on Linux. (You could probably use `date -f` if you add the `@` before each timestamp, but I am not in a place where I can test this right now.) Running a loop makes some things easier, such as printing both the input file name and the converted date, while otherwise a pipeline would be the most efficient and idiomatic solution.

As an aside, [basically never use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 4):

To convert epoch time to datetimem, please try the following command:

```
    date -d  @1346338800 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

1346338800 is a epoch time.

About your case, for comand line as following:

```
echo 1467535262.712041352 | cut -d '.' -f 1 | xargs -I{} date -d @{} +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

you will get:

```
20160703174102
```

Comment: You seem to lack the crucial `@` before the epoch value.

Comment: @gzh, this answer does not address the need to achieve this for multiple epoch values, via pipeline or via a restructured query per tripleee's answer

Comment: @StephLocke, please see my updated answer, for pipeline, you should use xargs command.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `-1` option to `ls` is useless, because ls prints its output one file per line by default, it's just that when the output is a terminal (not a pipe), it pretty-prints in columns. You can check that fact by just running `ls | cat`.

Then, date converts epoch timestamps safely only if prefixed with an `@`.

```
% date -d 0
Sun Jul  3 00:00:00 CEST 2016
% LANG=C date -d @0
Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 CET 1970

% date -d 12345
date: invalid date '12345'
% date -d @12345
Thu Jan  1 04:25:45 CET 1970
```

Which gives:

```
printf "%s\n" tmpBLAH/foo_*_bar.tar.gz | sed 's/.*foo_/@/; s/_bar.*//' | date -f -
```

Comment: You'll want to replace `ls` with e.g. `printf`. See also [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: This solution isn't working (the ifnal ls statement) - error is `date: option requires an argument -- 'f'`

Comment: Try `date -f -` with a dash as the argument to the `-f` option, like in your original attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for i in foo_*_bar.tar.gz; do date -d "@$(cut -d_ -f2 <<<"$i")" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'; done
```

The epoch time is provided with the `-d @<time>` and the desired format is `'+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`.

**Example:**

```
% for i in foo_*_bar.tar.gz; do date -d "@$(cut -d_ -f2 <<<"$i")" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'; done
20160703001158
20160703144102
```

Comment: That would mean that the wildcard didn't match. Try with your original wildcard.